# How to render codeblocks in MDXEditor?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I'm trying to use MDXEditor as my markdown editor in my app but when I'm trying to write some code snippets it doesn't work I mean it wont transform it to a html code tag and also I don't know what to do with the links because I cannot click on them, the documentation recommends using linkDialogPlugin but it's not shown properly I mean the position of the dialog is not right, I guess this is because I'm using tailwindcss. here is my code of MDXEditor:

```
<MDXEditor
      ref={editorRef}
      key={selectedNote.title}
      autoFocus
      onChange={handleAutoSaving}
      markdown={selectedNote.content}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      plugins={[
        headingsPlugin(),
        listsPlugin(),
        quotePlugin(),
        codeBlockPlugin({
          defaultCodeBlockLanguage: 'js'
        }),
        codeMirrorPlugin({
          theme: 'dark',
          codeBlockLanguages: { js: 'JavaScript', css: 'CSS' }
        }),
        linkPlugin(),
        markdownShortcutPlugin()
      ]}
      contentEditableClassName="outline-none min-h-screen max-w-none text-lg px-8 py-5 caret-yellow-500 
      prose prose-invert prose-p:my-3 prose-p:leading-relaxed prose-headings:my-4 prose-blockquote:my-4
       prose-ul:my-2 prose-li:my-0 prose-code:px-1 prose-code:text-red-500 prose-code:before:content-['']
       prose-code:after:content-[''] prose-a:text-blue-500 prose-a:hover:underline"
    />
```